# Display web pages of other websites on my WordPress blog

Tags: wordpress

Display web pages of other websites on my WordPress blog, in case I want to share any post, likewise on Facebook when you share some URL it appears with some preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is more than one plugin support URL preview on wordpress, here is the most good shaped one.

[link-preview](https://wordpress.org/plugins/link-preview/) <- Similar to facebook link preview
[embadly](https://wordpress.org/plugins/embedly/)